# Losing IPv4 configuration of Ethernet devices when configuring IPv6

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ip, ipv6

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu.

Inside a virtual machine I have some LXC containers

On every Ethernet device when I configure IPv6 the IPv4 connection drops.

The interface DOES NOT have an IPv4 address if an IPv6 address is configured. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could be easier to answer if you mentioned what steps you did to configure the IPv6 address.

Comment: Editing interfaces file from /etc/network